# How do I check to see if there is space in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

For part of schoolwork I need to write a `method` that goes through an array of objects to see if there is space to add another object to the `array`. If it was able to add an object then the `method` returns true and if it wasn't able to add it returns false. How do I check the `array` to see if there are empty cells in the array so I can add an element to the array? For example, I have an array that is size of 25 but only 15 cells are full and I want to add another object in one of the ten cells that are empty or `null`. This is essentially an add method with a `boolean` return value. But I need to know which cell I can add to and thus need to check which cell is empty or `null`.

Comment: What does "a space in an array" mean?

Comment: Is this array being filled from left to right, and your task is to determine whether the array is full with useful data or not?

Comment: Do you mean `null` at an index? Or do you mean `empty String ("")` inside a String array? Or do you mean a literal "Space" `" "` inside a String array?

Comment: You should make your question more clear.

Comment: Can't exactly follow what you specifically need. If an array is properly declared, you can always do array[i] to assign value at the index (i within bounds). Or if we are talking of Arraylist you can always .add() the element.

Comment: I am not sure what is not clear. How do I know that array[i] has no element inside there? That is what I need to check. If there is already an element in there how can I add another? If the array is full how can I add another element?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why I need to have tried something so far. Maybe I am not sure how to start? Is it always relevant what I have done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void isSpace(String[] array) {
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if( (array[i] == null) || (array[i].trim().length() == 0)) {
      //true on null, empty string, or white space only. Do something here
      array[i] = "add some thing here";
    }
    else {
      //not null, not empty string, or not white space. Do something here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an array as a static size, you could say that an array is always full.
But if you want to know array contains null values or not, you simply have to go through it.

```
public boolean isEmpty(Object[] array) {
   for (Object element : array) {
      if (element == null) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: side comment, you cant optimize your code iterating from tail, it all depends on how array is used, but it is more likely  to have null elements at the end than anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

Depends what do you mean, arrays are always initialized by their default type value, so you maybe trying to ask how to check if remained default values in array or not.

1) If you speak abot Object[] then you will check in this way:

```
public static boolean isSpace(Object[] array) {
   for (Object element : array)
       if (element == null) return true;
   return false;
}
```

2) If you speak abot primitive types like int[] then you will check in this way:

```
public static boolean isSpace(int[] array) {
   for (int element : array)
       if (element == 0) return true;
   return false;
}
```

However your question is not correctly formulated to understand you what you mean.

Comment: It is an objects array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isEmpty(Object[] array) {
   for (Object s : array) {
      if (s == null) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```